# time series charting replacement for rrdtool

Tags: javascript, time, charts, series

I have server data (multiple series) measured at varying time intervals from 15 seconds to 2 hours going back years. This data is in a sqlite database. I have been using rrdtool to enter this data into their round robin database format, and then to produce time charts (png files) from it which I then display in web pages. The rrdtool charts are really nice, but I dont want the hassle of maintaining two databases of the data, especially as we change the database schema during tooling updates.

What are the current best time series charting tools out there (open source). It can either be a stand alone tool that produces png files, or a javascript library. I just want to pass on timestamps and values and get out the chart, together with sensible scaling, axis labeling (either months, days, hours or a combo depending on scale). Also ability to overlay and stack multiple series, add legends and labeling.

I have looked briefly at gnuplot, google charts, chart.js and flot.
My server backend is java, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are generating PNG files on the server, then [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is one option for you - it has good support for time series charts, among other things.  For other open source Java chart libraries, you can look through the listing in [item 13 of the FAQ](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/faq.html#FAQ13).

Comment: You should also look at JRobin (it is in the list in the FAQ) which produces charts like rrdtool.  I've never used it, but as it is open source maybe you can keep the nice looking charts but fetch the data from your own database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `R`.
It can produce beautiful graphs. At the same time, it is a very lightweight tool.

You can create executable scripts very easily.

Here is a blogpost that describes how to access SQLite database from 'R`:

- http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-sqlite-part-1/

### Example:

And here is a working example that just renders some random signals:

[image]

Executable script that produced the image above.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript --default-packages=stats,utils,graphics,grDevices,argparser

p <- arg.parser("Sample script that generates a time-series into PNG file.")
p <- add.argument(p, "output.png", help = "The PNG file will be stored here")
argv <- parse.args(p)

# generating some random data (3 x time-series)
t <- 1:1024  # our time-span is 1024 seconds
ts1 <- runif(length(t), min=-1, max=1)  # uniform noise

period <- 2 * pi / length(t)
sinefreq <- 10  # frequency of our sine wave
ts2 <- sin(t * period * sinefreq)  # the sine wave signal
ts3 <- ts1 + ts2  # noise + signal

# writing the PNG to file
png(argv$output.png, width = 600, height = 500, pointsize = 12, res = 90)
{
  # two plots, each in a single row
  par(mfrow = c(2, 1), mar = c(4, 4, 2, 2))

  plot(ts1, type = "l", col = "red", xaxs="i", ylim=c(-4,4),
       main="Noise", ylab="Amplitude")

  plot(ts3, type = "l", col = "gray", xaxs="i",
       main="Noise modulated on a sine wave", ylab="Amplitude")

  # plotting over the previous diagram
  lines(ts2, col="blue", lwd=5)
}

cat("Image written to", argv$output.png, "\n")
```